# Is it possible programmatically to get the iPhone Name order preference?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, ios

In my iPhone app, I display a list of names. I want the name to be formatted either as
("First Name" "Last Name") or as ("Last Name, "First Name")

Is it possible to know the users' contact app preference using a API?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using ABPerson you can find out the users preference

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AddressBook/Reference/ABPersonRef_iPhoneOS/Reference/reference.html